# Plot multiple lines from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have the following table:

| Time | Type | Usage1 [%] | Usage2 [%] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-09 09:00 DST | LG1 | 60.0581 | 87.4926 |
| 2021-07-09 09:00 DST | LG2 | 42.1409 | 40.57 |
| 2021-07-09 09:00 DST | LG3 | 63.433 | 49.9326 |
| 2021-07-09 10:00 DST | LG1 | 53.6577 | 86.6658 |
| 2021-07-09 10:00 DST | LG2 | 36.384 | 41.7439 |
| 2021-07-09 10:00 DST | LG3 | 54.5699 | 54.0306 |
| 2021-07-10 09:00 DST | LG1 | 35.2818 | 75.8487 |
| 2021-07-10 09:00 DST | LG2 | 34.101 | 37.7934 |
| 2021-07-10 09:00 DST | LG3 | 50.4009 | 46.8263 |
| 2021-07-10 10:00 DST | LG1 | 39.3575 | 78.3179 |
| 2021-07-10 10:00 DST | LG2 | 50.3955 | 43.3913 |
| 2021-07-10 10:00 DST | LG3 | 52.2898 | 51.8793 |
| 2021-07-11 09:00 DST | LG1 | 36.8559 | 71.9565 |
| 2021-07-11 09:00 DST | LG2 | 31.1939 | 35.8108 |
| 2021-07-11 09:00 DST | LG3 | 44.6744 | 49.5196 |
| 2021-07-11 10:00 DST | LG1 | 43.9611 | 74.5974 |
| 2021-07-11 10:00 DST | LG2 | 39.075 | 36.9884 |
| 2021-07-11 10:00 DST | LG3 | 41.0939 | 45.0962 |

I want the x-axis to be Time, and then plot a line in the graph for Usage1 and Usage2 for each Type.
So in total, since there are 3 different Types, there should be a total of 6 lines.
So far I've tried the following code but it plots a single line for each Usage:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel (r'plot.xlsx')

plt.plot( 'Time', 'Usage1 [%]', data=df, marker='o', linewidth=2, label='Type')
plt.plot( 'Time', 'Usage2 [%]', data=df, marker='o', linewidth=2, label='Type')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reshape your data to look like this using [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html):

```
                    Time  Type    variable    value
0  2021-07-09 09:00 DST   LG1   Usage1 [%]  60.0581
1  2021-07-09 09:00 DST   LG2   Usage1 [%]  42.1409
2  2021-07-09 09:00 DST   LG3   Usage1 [%]  63.4330
3  2021-07-09 10:00 DST   LG1   Usage1 [%]  53.6577
4  2021-07-09 10:00 DST   LG2   Usage1 [%]  36.3840
```

Then you can use [seaborn.lineplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
sns.lineplot(data=df.melt(id_vars=['Time', 'Type']), x='Time', hue='Type', style='variable', y='value')
```

output:

[image: seaborn line plot]

NB. to ensure consistent time handling, it is better to [use the datetime format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for your time column.

Comment: is there anyway of doing it with matplotlib?

Comment: seaborn is using matplotlib, so you end up with a Axes object here.

Comment: For sure you can also do it manually by looping over the Type and Usage, but what would be the reason for not using seaborn? If there is a specific reason, please update your question

Comment: I don't have seaborn installed and I currently don't have permission to do it